# Delete all items in a DynamoDB table using bash with both partition and sort keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I'm trying to delete all items in a DynamoDB table that has both partition and sort keys using AWS CLI in bash. [The best thing I've found so far](https://gist.github.com/pushplay/d2cac7ca1a10a5a49f6947a02657a23a) is:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name $TABLE_NAME --attributes-to-get "$KEY" \
--query "Items[].$KEY.S" --output text | \
tr "\t" "\n" | \
xargs -t -I keyvalue aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name $TABLE_NAME \
--key "{\"$KEY\": {\"S\": \"keyvalue\"}}"
```

But this does not work with a table that has both the partition key and the sort key, and I have not yet been able to make it work with such a table. Any idea how to modify the script to make it work for a table with composite keys?

Comment: FYI the awscli recommends that you use --projection-expression rather than --attributes-to-get.

Comment: Using all answers I could find and the great gnu parallel, I came out with a nifty and fast solution https://gist.github.com/BuonOmo/f415466c4af38f236c11d879099af7cf

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Depending on the size of your table this can be too expensive and result in downtime. Remember that deletes cost you the same as a write, so you'll get throttled by your provisioned WCU.  It would be *much simpler and faster* to just delete and recreate the table.

```
# this uses jq but basically we're just removing 
# some of the json fields that describe an existing 
# ddb table and are not actually part of the table schema/defintion
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name $table_name | jq '.Table | del(.TableId, .TableArn, .ItemCount, .TableSizeBytes, .CreationDateTime, .TableStatus, .ProvisionedThroughput.NumberOfDecreasesToday)' > schema.json
# delete the table
aws dynamodb delete-table --table-name $table_name
# create table with same schema (including name and provisioned capacity)
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://schema.json
```

If you really want to you can delete each item individually and you're on the right track you just need to specify both the hash and range keys in your scan projection and delete command.

```
aws dynamodb scan \
  --attributes-to-get $HASH_KEY $RANGE_KEY \
  --table-name $TABLE_NAME --query "Items[*]" \
  # use jq to get each item on its own line
  | jq --compact-output '.[]' \
  # replace newlines with null terminated so 
  # we can tell xargs to ignore special characters 
  | tr '\n' '\0' \
  | xargs -0 -t -I keyItem \
    # use the whole item as the key to delete (dynamo keys *are* dynamo items)
    aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name $TABLE_NAME --key=keyItem
```

If you want to get super fancy you can use the `describe-table` call to fetch the hash and range key to populate `$HASH_KEY` and `$RANGE_KEY` but i'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: I really like the idea of deleting and recreating the table, but I wonder if there s a way to do it without jq (and without long complicated string manipulation).

Comment: You can certainly do it without jq, you'll just wind up writing a subset of jq to manipulate JSON.  To replace jq you just have to use some bash magic to remove certain JSON fields. Nothing comes for free :)

Comment: If I delete and recreate the table (with the same name), will I be guaranteed a same ARN?

Comment: DDB ARNs are defined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-ddb As long as you have the same table name it will be the same table ARN. (Streams will be different)

Comment: Is there a way to parallel process the deletion?

Comment: Just realized that adding option `-P 8` to xargs can parallel the processing up to 8 threads. Usually deleting 100 records take me 3 minutes, and after adding this option, it takes 30 seconds.

Comment: Don't follow this advise if you have partitioned your table to a high amount of partitions. It might cost a lot more to partition it back to 500-1000 partitions.

Comment: @Cheruvian Great solution. When I try to create the table, it complains about `BillingModeSummary` and `Invalid value for parameter ProvisionedThroughput.ReadCapacityUnits, value: 0, valid min value: 1`

Comment: The idea of delete and recreate the table is good, but I don't adopt it because I have ddb stream enabled and recreating it requires me to update the stream arn for its dependencies.

Comment: Just want to point out that manually deleting/creating a table is not a great idea if you use IaC provisioning like CloudFormation.

Comment: For what it's worth, this answer sometimes needs to be modified. For example, running on a table today resulted in: `Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "BillingModeSummary", must be one of: AttributeDefinitions, TableName, KeySchema, LocalSecondaryIndexes, GlobalSecondaryIndexes, BillingMode, ProvisionedThroughput, StreamSpecification, ....
Invalid value for parameter ProvisionedThroughput.ReadCapacityUnits, value: 0, valid min value: 1
Invalid value for parameter ProvisionedThroughput.WriteCapacityUnits, value: 0, valid min value: 1`

Answer (score 14):

TO correct what @Cheruvian has posted. The following commands work, there are few more fields we need to exclude while creating schema.json.

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name $table_name | jq '.Table | del(.TableId, .TableArn, .ItemCount, .TableSizeBytes, .CreationDateTime, .TableStatus, .LatestStreamArn, .LatestStreamLabel, .ProvisionedThroughput.NumberOfDecreasesToday, .ProvisionedThroughput.LastIncreaseDateTime)' > schema.json

aws dynamodb delete-table --table-name $table_name

aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://schema.json
```

Comment: There may be a slight issue with this method in that the most recent version of the schema also returns `LastDecreaseDateTIme`:

aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://schema.json

Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in ProvisionedThroughput: "LastDecreaseDateTime", must be one of: ReadCapacityUnits, WriteCapacityUnits

This is easily fixed by deleting that line in the schema.json file.

Comment: Yeah. In new schema versions we should add `, .ProvisionedThroughput.LastDecreaseDateTime` to line #1

Answer (score 7):

If you are interested in doing it with Node.js, have a look at this example (I'm using TypeScript here). Further related infos can be found in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property).

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const DynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
region: 'eu-west-1'

});
export const getAllItemsFromTable = async TableName => {
   const Res = await DynamoDb.scan({ TableName }).promise();
   return Res.Items;
};

export const deleteAllItemsFromTable = async (TableName = '', items:{ id: string }, hashKey) => {
  var counter = 0;
  //split items into patches of 25
  // 25 items is max for batchWrite
  asyncForEach(split(items, 25), async (patch, i) => {
    const RequestItems = {
      TableName: patch.map(item => {
        return {
          DeleteRequest: {
            Key: {
              id: item.id
            }
          }
        };
      })
    };
    await DynamoDb.batchWrite({ RequestItems }).promise();
    counter += patch.length;
    console.log('counter : ', counter);
  });
};

function split(arr, n) {
  var res = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    res.push(arr.splice(0, n));
  }
  return res;
}

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}

const tableName = "table"
// assuming table hashKey is named "id"
deleteAllItemsFromTable(tableName,getAllItemsFromTable(tableName))
```

Comment: I needed to run this code, so I made it into an easy-to-run app: https://github.com/sibljon/batch-delete-dynamo-db-table-items/blob/master/index.ts

Comment: and for the above code, if items are not unique by their hashkey, you'll need to provide the sortkey name

Answer (score 3):

I've created a node module to do this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-empty

```
yarn global add dynamodb-empty
dynamodb-empty --table tableName
```

Comment: Hey this looks awesome. Is that on Github?

Comment: @Gambo perhaps it is https://github.com/skyhookadventure/dynamodb-empty

Answer (score 0):

We had some tables with indexes, so there had to be deleted some fields more, additionally the ".ProvisionedThroughput.LastDecreaseDateTime".
Was a little work to fiddle out as i'm totally new to jq ;-)
But this is how it worked for us:

```
    aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name $table_name | jq '.Table | del(.TableId, .TableArn, .ItemCount, .TableSizeBytes, .CreationDateTime, .TableStatus, .LatestStreamArn, .LatestStreamLabel, .ProvisionedThroughput.NumberOfDecreasesToday, .ProvisionedThroughput.LastIncreaseDateTime, .ProvisionedThroughput.LastDecreaseDateTime, .GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].IndexSizeBytes, .GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].ProvisionedThroughput.NumberOfDecreasesToday, .GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].IndexStatus, .GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].IndexArn, .GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].ItemCount)' > schema.json
```

Answer (score 0):

From the @Adel and @codeperson answers here I made a function using Amplify CLI (With Hello World template), where the table name has to be passed using the event object:

```
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    API_DEALSPOON_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT
    API_DEALSPOON_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const environment = process.env.ENV
const region = process.env.REGION
const apiDealspoonGraphQLAPIIdOutput = process.env.API_DEALSPOON_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const DynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region});

    // const tableName = "dev-invite";
    // const hashKey = "InviteToken";
    let {tableName, hashKey} = event
    
    tableName = `${tableName}-${apiDealspoonGraphQLAPIIdOutput}'-'${environment}`
    
    // Customization 4: add logic to determine which (return true if you want to delete the respective item)
    // If you don't want to filter anything out, then just return true in this function (or remove the filter step below, where this filter is used)
    const shouldDeleteItem = (item) => {
        return item.Type === "SECURE_MESSAGE" || item.Type === "PATIENT";
    };

    const getAllItemsFromTable = async (lastEvaluatedKey) => {
        const res = await DynamoDb.scan({
            TableName: tableName,
            ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey
        }).promise();
        return {items: res.Items, lastEvaluatedKey: res.LastEvaluatedKey};
    };

    const deleteAllItemsFromTable = async (items) => {
        let numItemsDeleted = 0;
        // Split items into patches of 25
        // 25 items is max for batchWrite
        await asyncForEach(split(items, 25), async (patch, i) => {
            const requestItems = {
                [tableName]: patch.filter(shouldDeleteItem).map(item => {
                    numItemsDeleted++;
                    return {
                        DeleteRequest: {
                            Key: {
                                [hashKey]: item[hashKey]
                            }
                        }
                    };
                })
            };
            if (requestItems[tableName].length > 0) {
                await DynamoDb.batchWrite({RequestItems: requestItems}).promise();
                console.log(`finished deleting ${numItemsDeleted} items this batch`);
            }
        });

        return {numItemsDeleted};
    };

    function split(arr, n) {
        const res = [];
        while (arr.length) {
            res.push(arr.splice(0, n));
        }
        return res;
    }

    async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
        for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            await callback(array[index], index, array);
        }
    }

    let lastEvaluatedKey;
    let totalItemsFetched = 0;
    let totalItemsDeleted = 0;

    console.log(`------ Deleting from table ${tableName}`);

    do {
        const {items, lastEvaluatedKey: lek} = await getAllItemsFromTable(lastEvaluatedKey);
        totalItemsFetched += items.length;
        console.log(`--- a group of ${items.length} was fetched`);

        const {numItemsDeleted} = await deleteAllItemsFromTable(items);
        totalItemsDeleted += numItemsDeleted;
        console.log(`--- ${numItemsDeleted} items deleted`);

        lastEvaluatedKey = lek;
    } while (!!lastEvaluatedKey);

    console.log("Done!");
    console.log(`${totalItemsFetched} items total fetched`);
    console.log(`${totalItemsDeleted} items total deleted`);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used some examples here and created an code which actually take the parameters, delete, and re-create the table... working fine:

```
TABLE_NAME='<your_table_name>' ;\
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name $TABLE_NAME \
|jq '.Table + .Table.BillingModeSummary
|del(.TableId, .TableArn, .ItemCount, .TableSizeBytes, .CreationDateTime, 
.TableStatus, .ProvisionedThroughput, .BillingModeSummary, 
.LastUpdateToPayPerRequestDateTime, .GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].IndexStatus, 
.GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].IndexSizeBytes, 
.GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].ItemCount, .GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].IndexArn, 
.GlobalSecondaryIndexes[].ProvisionedThroughput)' > tb_schema.json
aws dynamodb delete-table --table-name $TABLE_NAME
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://tb_schema.json
```