# How to delete all items the table in a Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I tried to delete all items using the PartiQL in AWS, but i receive that message

```
delete from myfile


An error occurred during the execution of the command.
ValidationException: Where clause does not contain a mandatory equality on all key attributes
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all items in a DynamoDB table using bash with both partition and sort keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660198/delete-all-items-in-a-dynamodb-table-using-bash-with-both-partition-and-sort-key)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Seems pretty straight forward...

> ValidationException: Where clause does not contain a mandatory
> equality on all key attributes

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.delete.html)

The syntax is

> DELETE FROM table
> WHERE condition [RETURNING returnvalues]

and furthermore

> condition (Required)
> The selection criteria for the item to be deleted; this condition must resolve to a single primary key value.

If you want to delete all records in DDB, delete the table and recreate it.

Comment: Would be nice to see example

Comment: @AlexanderMatrosov How do you provide an example of something that can't be done?

Comment: The pretty forward conclusion is simply to stay away from `DynamoDB`.

Comment: @W.M. no, the conclusion is to use DDB for it's designed purposes, and not to expect it to work like a RDBMS.

Comment: @Charles , I agree that needs should guide DB choice and schema design but what if for some reason, there is a need to update all documents which match a certain condition? The only solution it seems in DynamoDB, is to loop through all of them, in code, one by one and update them. There should be a built in mechanism to do that, yes, simply in a manner that resembles a RDBMS, using a single statement.

Answer (score 4):

I've got this error when I queried the filters with double quotes ("), but they are single quotes (') even though the fields themselves are double quotes.

Here's the WRONG way (the one i've got the same error as you):

```
DELETE FROM "TABLE_A" WHERE "PK" = "<PK_A>" AND "SK" < "2022-03-27T14:10:00.000Z"
```

Here's the RIGHT way(at least the way it worked for me):

```
DELETE FROM "TABLE_A" WHERE "PK" = '<PK_A>' AND "SK" < '2022-03-27T14:10:00.000Z'
```

Comment: the OP is trying to delete all records

Comment: DELETE only supports removal of one row, so it won't work with < operator